# Change from Date to calendar

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I have the following code ,how should I change it from date to return type calendar ?

```
    Date date = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        // TODO handle exception
        try {
            date = parsedDate.parse((String) memberValue);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new SwitchInputType<Date>(date);
```

Comment: I've down-voted because you've shown zero evidence of prior research and effort on your part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:-

```
Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```